# Tlbimp .net and COM components still need to be registered

Tags: .net, com, interop, tlbimp

I took a COM DLL and used tlbimp to create a DLL I could use in my .net 3.5 project. I'm getting an error though when try to use the COM interface and I'm wondering if I still need to register the COM dll on the server the app will be installed on? If so, which DLL do I register, the one created with tlpimp or the original one I used with tlpimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I still need to register the COM dll on the server the app will be installed on?

Yes. The .NET type library that is generated is just a managed wrapper - the original COM Lib must still be registered.

> If so, which DLL do I register, the one created with tlpimp or the original one I used with tlpimp?

Usually with `regsvr32.exe`. You would use that on the original that you used with tlbimp. Better yet, if it gets installed with an installer like an MSI, use that instead.